# Checking filesystem integrity of USB drive in Windows Java

Tags: java, winapi, com, jna

Our application involves an external device that mounts as a USB mass storage device. I need to be able to check the integrity of that USB mass storage device from a Java application, running on Windows.

Currently I execute "chkdsk", which works fine unless the user's computer isn't configured for English. (Because I need to examine the chkdsk output to determine the state of the drive.) And, surprise, surprise, not every computer in the world is configured for English!

There is a Win32 class called "Win32_Volume" with a method called "Chkdsk" that is just what I'm looking for.

I need to call it from Java, and JNA seems the way to go.

How can I use COM to call a method from a Win32 WMI class?

Comment: The original question edged on asking for recommendations to off-site resources, which is off-topic here. I've edited your question to more clearly state the on-topic programming question you were asking.

Comment: @Bill Evans I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Calling a WMI Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/calling-a-method)

Answer (score 0):

You can send an [FSCTL_IS_VOLUME_DIRTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/fsctl-is-volume-dirty) message using [DeviceIoControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/calling-deviceiocontrol) is and example of calling DeviceIoControl.

Or you can use WMI, both the the [Win32_Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/win32-volume) and the [Win32_LogicalDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk) class expose a `DirtyBitSet` property. However WMI is really inteded for scripting languages and is not preferred because of it's incredible performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The [Win32_Volume documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394515(v=vs.85)) with the `Chkdsk` method you cite indicates it is a legacy API, but has not yet been deprecated so you could use it.

The current Storage Management API equivalent is [MSFT_Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/msft-volume).  It has a `Diagnose` method that looks to perform similar functionality.

To execute a method on a WMI object via COM you need to obtain a pointer to a `WbemServices` object.  It has an `ExecMethod` method you can invoke that does what you want for WMI classes.  The code to retrieve this object is in JNA's WbemcliUtil class as a return type from the [connectServer()](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.10.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/WbemcliUtil.html#connectServer-java.lang.String-) method.

You will also need the full path to the Class Object; this is available by querying WMI for the `__PATH`, similarly to how you'd query any other field.  That same `WbemcliUtil` class has a `WmiQuery` class you can instantiate to execute the query, collecting that path from the `WmiResult`.  See the JNA test classes for examples on using these.

Finally, you can execute the WMI method.  The code below will accomplish it for String properties, e.g., the [`MSFT_StorageDiagnoseResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/msft-storagediagnoseresult) object you'd get from `MSFT_Volume`'s `Diagnose` method.  You'd have to treat other return types differently.

```java
/**
 * Convenience method for executing WMI methods without any input parameters
 * 
 * @param svc
 *            The WbemServices object
 * @param clsObj
 *            The full path to the class object to execute (result of WMI
 *            "__PATH" query)
 * @param method
 *            The name of the method to execute
 * @param properties
 *            One or more properties returned as a result of the query
 * @return An array of the properties returned from the method
 */
private static String[] execMethod(WbemServices svc, String clsObj, String method, String... properties) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    PointerByReference ppOutParams = new PointerByReference();
    HRESULT hres = svc.ExecMethod(new BSTR(clsObj), new BSTR(method), new NativeLong(0L), null, null, ppOutParams,
            null);
    if (COMUtils.FAILED(hres)) {
        return new String[0];
    }
    WbemClassObject obj = new WbemClassObject(ppOutParams.getValue());
    VARIANT.ByReference vtProp = new VARIANT.ByReference();
    for (String prop : properties) {
        hres = obj.Get(new BSTR(prop), new NativeLong(0L), vtProp, null, null);
        if (!COMUtils.FAILED(hres)) {
            result.add(vtProp.getValue() == null ? "" : vtProp.stringValue());
        }
    }
    obj.Release();
    return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
}
```

A more complete example of querying a COM object, where I extracted the above code, is in [this utility class](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/731900678b305898ac5adeb7f036a551e5f03713/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/util/platform/windows/WmiUtil.java) which queries the `GetOwner()` and `GetOwnerSid()` methods on the `Win32_Process` object.  It's legacy code from before I contributed the `WbemCli` class to JNA, so you'll have to adapt some of it, but it should be a good starting point.